# How do I access movieclip from a copied loader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am having trouble accessing the movieclip and the child movieclips of a copied loader.
I am loading a swf like,

```
var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myswf.swf");
ldr.load(urlReq);
```

and using this to display on stage,

```
stage.addChild(ldr);
(ldr.content as MovieClip).star.gotoAndStop(2);
```

I needed a copy of this so I copied it using the code,

```
var newLoader:Loader = new Loader();
newLoader.loadBytes(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
```

and using it as,

```
var myObj:DisplayObject = newLoader;
tempMC.addChild(myObj);
```

Now there is a movieClip called 'star' inside the actual loaded swf how do I use it???
Please help.... :(

Comment: myObj == newLoader so (newLoader.content as MovieClip).star - did you tried that?

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I did tried it but it gives error saying "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("myswf.swf");
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplereHandler);
ldr.load(urlReq);


function loaderComplereHandler(event:Event) :void {
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderComplereHandler);
    var mc:MovieClip = event.target.content as MovieClip;
    addChild(mc);
    mc.getChildByName("star").rotation=50;

    var newLoader:Loader = new Loader();
    newLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCopyComplereHandler);
    newLoader.loadBytes(ldr.contentLoaderInfo.bytes);
}

function loaderCopyComplereHandler(event:Event) :void {
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderCopyComplereHandler);
    var mc2:MovieClip = event.target.content as MovieClip;
    mc2.x = 100;
    addChild(mc2);
    mc2.getChildByName("star").rotation=90;
}
```

Also you not need to make copy of `ldr` with `loadBytes`. You can use `ldr` to make many instance of `myswf.swf` after loading complete...

Comment: Hey Smolniy,  Perfectly said man... It worked as a charm, Thanks a tons for your help. You ROCK... Thanks again....